# Read value from list view row

Tags: android, listview

I display in a list view some team members. The plan is to get the teamId with the maximum number of steps. The below method demonstrates how I am achieving that.

```
public void readLeagueMembers(JSONObject response){


    JSONArray teamsArray = null;
    try {
        teamsArray = response.getJSONArray("teams");
        for (int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length(); i++) {

            leagueMembers = new LeagueMembers();
            JSONObject team = teamsArray.getJSONObject(i);

            leagueMembers.setTeamId(team.getString("ID"));
            leagueMembers.setTeams(team.getString("team_name"));

            leagueMembers.setLeaguePoints(team.getString("team_points"));

            leagueMembersList.add(leagueMembers);
            listView.setAdapter(leagueAdapter);


            //String[] team_points = new String[]{leagueMembers.getLeaguePoints()};
            teamId = leagueMembersList.get(0).getTeamId();
            Log.d("teamId",teamId);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You see from that method the variable teamId(which is static) where it stores the first row's teamId which is 645.

Now I am passing this value to another class which is a CountDownTimer one.

```
 public class CounterClass1 extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass1(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = minutes / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;
        String time = days+"d"+ ":" + hours % 24+"h" + ":" + minutes % 60 +"m"+ ":" + seconds % 60+"s";

        diffDays.setText("League finishes in: " + time);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        diffDays.setText("League Finished");
        viewResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        leagueInvitation.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         winnerId = League.teamId;
        Log.d("team id",winnerId);

        viewResults(leagueId, winnerId, results, username, password);

    }
}
```

As shown I read the static variable teamId from another class

```
winnerId = League.teamId;
```

and store it to a variable called winnerId. Unfortunately winnerId is read as null from the debugger. Any suggestions? Surely it is a Java problem not an Android one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all where is your leagueadapter. Whare you initialize it . And second thing you are setting adapter inside loop that is wrong. It will set adpter again and again if you have more that one oblect inside json array .

And for the team id you can create a singleton class and set team id there in a instance varible .and get that id whereever you want .Here is tha code fro singleton class you need .

```
public class ReferenceWrapper {
private static ReferenceWrapper wrapper;
private int teamId;
private Context context;
private ReferenceWrapper(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
}

public static ReferenceWrapper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (wrapper == null) {
        wrapper = new ReferenceWrapper(context);
    }
    return wrapper;
}

public int getTeamId(int teamId) {
    return teamId;
}

public int setTeamId() {
    this.teamId=teamId;
}
```

}

Comment: Fixed!!! I had to take care of my Singleton class or POJO object(I think this is what is called) . Thanks.